# Will CUDA API affect CPU's Ram access performance?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, cuda

*** More testing shows CPU's Ram slowness is not related to CUDA. It turns out Func2(CPU) is CPU intensive but not memory intensive, then for my program1, the pressure on memory is less as it's Func2 who is occupying CPU. For program2(GPU), as Func2 becomes very fast with GPU, Func1 occupies CPU and put a lot of pressure on memory, leading to Func1's slowness ***

Short version: if I run 20 processes concurrently on the same server, I noticed CPU's running speed is much slower when GPU is involved (vs pure CPU processes)

Long version:

My server: Win Server 2012, 48 cores (hyperthreaded from 24), 192 GB Ram (the 20 processes will only use ~40GB), 4 K40 cards

My program1 (CPU Version):

```
    For 30 iterations:  
        Func1(CPU): 6s (lot's CPU memory access)
        Func2(CPU): 60s (lot's CPU memory access)
```

My program2 (GPU Version, **to use CPU cores for Func1, and K40s for Func2):**

```
   //1 K40 will hold 5 contexts at the same time, till end of the 30 iterations
   cudaSetDevice  //very slow, can be few seconds
   cudaMalloc ~1GB //can be another few seconds
   For 30 iterations:  
        Func1(CPU): 6s
        Func2(GPU), 1s (60X speedup) //share GPU via named_mutex
```

If I run 20 program1(CPU) together, I noticed Func1's 6s becomes 12s on average

While for 20 program2(GPU), Func1 takes **~42s** to complete, while my Func2(GPU) is still ~1s (This 1s includes locking GPU, some cudaMemcpy & the kernel call. I presume this includes GPU context switching also). So seems GPU's own performance is not affected much, while CPU does (by GPU)

So I suspect cudaSetDevice/cudaMalloc/cudaMemcpy is affecting CPU's Ram access? If it's true, parallelization using both multi-core CPU & GPU will be affected.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a down vote. Pls explain your reason to help me improve, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by resource contention.

When, in the standard API, you run 20 processes, you have 20 separate GPU contexts. Every time one of those processes wishes to perform an API call, there must be a context switch to that processes context. Context switching is expensive and has a lot of latency. That will be the source of the slow down you are seeing. Nothing to do with memory performance.

NVIDIA has released a system called MPS (Multi Process Server) which reimplements the CUDA API as a service and internally exploits the Hyper-Q facility of modern TesLa cards to push operations onto the wide command queue which Hyper-Q supports. This removes all the context switching latency. It sounds like you might want to investigate this, if performances is important to you and your code requires a large number of processes sharing a single device

Comment: Hi talonmies, thanks for the answer. But my log shows GPU's performance is not affected much by the 20 processes. (Have modified my question to reflect it), thanks

Comment: found the real cause and I've explained in question edit.